# Problems with GMM (Generalized Methods of Moments) in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

I am interested in performing an analysis using a GMM model for a panel dataset.

I am conducting the analysis in R, using the `pgmm` package. My code is the following:

```r
GMM_results <- pgmm(Firm Value ~ Efficiency + SIZE + Performance +  
    Leverage + Sales Growth + Firm Age | Industry, 
    data = dataset, effect = "twoways", model = "twostep", 
    transformation = "ld")
```

Now, my results are robust for autocorrelation: AR (1) signficant results and AR(1) not significant.  But for the Sargan test for overidentification restrictions, I receive this: `Sargan test: chisq(47) = 877.707 (p-value = < 0.000000000000000222)`

In fact, this result remains unchanged, even when I switch to a system GMM (instead of difference GMM), if I change the effect to individual or if I perform onestep only.
Also, if I include more or other instruments - my Sargan test is always significant.

In my understanding, this means that the set of instruments is not valid. Is there any way I can change my code (e.g. including more lagged values) in order to change my Sargan value?